# Can I sublease my apartment without my co-tenants approval in Indiana

Tags: rent, lease, sublease, indiana

I’m currently studying at Purdue University in Indiana and I want to sublease my apartment for the summer.

One of my co-tenants who is also on the lease is not agreeing to sign the sublease form. But my landlord has no objection in me doing that.

Can I still get a sublease and make a contract with her?

Comment: What does your contract with the landlord say? Does it specify that you need you co-tenant's approval?

Comment: In addition to @brhans's comment, I would ask whether you have a contract with the co-tenant.